# How to start a Service in Android?

Tags: java, android, class

I have 3 classes in separate java files: `try.java`, `HU.java`, and `First.java`.

The `Hu` class is not an activity, it's a service, and when `First.java` runs I have this code that calls the `Hu` class:

```
public class First extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent svc = new Intent(this, Hu.class);
        startService(svc);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I know this code works, because the `Hu` class is called.

Since the `Hu` class is a service, it is an "always on top button", and I use `onTouchListener` to register to a click event, and that part works. What does not work is the part where I call the `Try` class when the button is clicked.

That is in a separate Java file; here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Overlay button event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent svc1 = new Intent(this, Try.class);
    startService(svc1);

    return false;
}
```

I use the same logic here, but it is not working.

Comment: That's not how you "call a class", that's how you start a Service in Android. Is `Try` a Service?

Comment: `startService()` -- this expects a service class !

Comment: ok sorry, try is a service (edited)

Comment: so why you are calling a activity by calling startService() method get the basic first from the AndroidDeveloper site.

Comment: `this` from `onTouch` refers to a valid `Context`? Also, is the service `Try` registered in Manifest?

Comment: API docs include example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html